# Vue.js v-for looping over array not working (zero elements with non-zero length)

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm running into a very strange issue: I have a Vue component that shows a list of items using `v-for`. Once in a while the list will be empty although there are 20 items in the array. I even print the length of the array and it outputs `20`.

I use `Vue.extend` to define a custom component. Here are the relevant parts:

```
const myComponent = Vue.extend(
{
    template:'<ul>\
                    <li >Length: {{ contentRows.length }}</li>\
                    <li v-for="row in contentRows">{{ row }}</li>\
                </ul>\ ',
    data() { 
        return { contentRows: [], }
    },

    created() {
        this.contentRows = this._loadContentRows()
    },

    methods: {
        _loadContentRows() {
            // Array of arrays, fetched from external source:
            return this.dataSource.contentRows() 
        },
    }
})
```

The above generates the following invalid HTML output once in a while (about 1 out of 10 page loads):

```
<ul>
    <li >Length: 20</li>
    <!-- MISSING LIST ITEMS HERE, note how length says 20... -->
</ul>
```

The length of my `contentRows` data property shows correctly as `20`, but looping though the rows returns zero items.

I added some debug statements to vue.js in `renderList(val, render)` at line 3294 (v2.2.0)

```
 function renderList ( val, render) {
  var ret, i, l, keys, key;
  if (Array.isArray(val) || typeof val === 'string') {
    ret = new Array(val.length);
    console.log('reg length: ' + ret.length + 
               ' val.length = ' + val.length + ' val: ' +
                 val + ' val.length = ' + val.length)
    for (i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i++) {
      ret[i] = render(val[i], i);
    }
    [...]
```

The above prints:

```
[Log] reg length: 0 val.length = 0 val: row1,row2,...row20, val.length = 0
```

Note how the length is 0, but there is a value. How is this possible?

At first I thought maybe it is a timing issue and the value of `val` is changed somewhere else, but I print the length, the value, and the length once more. Strangely enough, if I print val.length at the end of the `renderList` function, it returns the correct value of 20.

**UPDATE:**

I can reproduce this with v2.1.8 and v2.2.0. The problem is at line 3199 (v2.1.8) and 3294 (v2.2.0): `for (i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i++) {`. val.length returns 0 although there are 20 items in the array.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a fiddle/codepen?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "key" with your "v-for" :

```
<li v-for="(row, index) in contentRows" :key="'row' + index">{{ row }}</li>
```

See [v2.2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.2.0?utm_campaign=Revue%20newsletter&utm_medium=Newsletter&utm_source=revue):

> When using v-for with a component, a key is now required. You will likely see a bunch of "soft warnings" when you upgrade, but this does not affect the current behavior of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried the key, but the problem still exists. I tested this with due v2.1.8 and v2.2.0. The problem is at line 3199 (v2.1.8) and 3294 (v2.2.0: `for (i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i++) {`. val.length returns 0 although there are 20 items in the array.

Comment: Why use "const" : const myComponent = Vue.extend({}); ?
Maybe this const block the update of the variable.

Comment: No, I don't think that's the cause. I instantiate new components with new myComponent(). It works most of the cases and only about one out of 10 is the length 0.